# How to use init construct in Kotlin in elegant way

Tags: oop, syntax, kotlin

There are many [examples](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors) how to use `init` during class construction, but they are mostly without using actual class properties.

What I need to do is init a class property from database on object init. So far I have this:

```
class MyObj constructor(val id: Long){

   var data: MutableMap? = null

   init {
       data = db.find(id) // more like pseudocode, db fetch is done and result assigned to data property
   }
}
```

But it seems a little overcomplicated to me. Is there any better, more elegant way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write:

```
class MyObj constructor(val id: Long){
    val data: Map<String, String> = mapOf()
}
```

It's equivalent to:

```
class MyObj constructor(val id: Long){
    val data: Map<String, String>
    init {
        data = mapOf()
    }
}
```

Init block is useful if you need introduce some logic for your object initialization, like error checking etc. Ofc you can do it with or without init block. But remember what is more readable:

```
class MyObj constructor(val id: Long){
    val data: Map<String, String> = if (id == 0L) {
        mapOf(Pair("", ""))
    } else {
        throw IllegalStateException()
    }
} // without init

class MyObj constructor(val id: Long){
    val data: Map<String, String>

    init {
        data = if (id == 0L) {
            mapOf(Pair("", ""))
        } else {
            throw IllegalStateException()
        }
    }
} // with init
```

You can also init this value using lazy (what means property will be initialized as function, but value will be assigned when you first ask for it, not when object is created). I guess taking value from db can be quite long, so it may be useful:

```
val data: Map<String, String> by lazy { mapOf() }
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this as there are some additional hints I've found useful. Thanks :)

Comment: If the error check is just for null, it can be probably shortened like this `val data: Map = db.find(id) ?: throw IllegalStateException()`. So it can stay on one line and also the target variable doesn't have to be nullable.

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize the property directly in the class body:

```
class MyObj(val id: Long) {
     val data: MutableMap = db.find(id)
}
```

Then you won't need to declare it as a nullable type, and may be able to use `val` instead of `var`. (I've also removed the `constructor` keyword which is redundant.).

Comment: Can't you use a non-nullable `val` with `init` as well?

Comment: Yes, you can, if you remove the `= null` initializer

Comment: Which is redundant if you assign in `init`, right? There's no case in which it would make a difference. In other words, you should remove the `= null` with or without `init`.

Comment: I feel a little stupid now :) Still have a lot to learn about Kotlin. It seems that every time I write something long, it is probably not well written and there is some simpler solution. Nice!